# gnuplot iteration-- max iterable value?

Tags: iteration, gnuplot

I can plot a function with variable values as large as I need in gnuplot 4.4:

```
gnuplot> t = 10000*365.25*24*3600
gnuplot> f(x) = alpha*delta*exp(-alpha*x)*(sin(omega*t-alpha*x)-cos(omega*t-alpha*x))
gnuplot> plot f(x)
```

But If I instead want to iterate over t using similar values as above, by using the `plot for' command, I get segfaults or it doesn't seem to end (I waited a long time and still no response):

```
tau = int(40000*365.25*24*3600)
step = int(10000*365.25*24*3600)
f(x,t) = alpha*delta*exp(-alpha*x)*(sin(omega*t-alpha*x)-cos(omega*t-alpha*x))
plot for [t=0:tau:step] f(x,t)
```

If I have tau = 1000, and step = 10 then there is no problem, so I'm assuming that the size of the iterables is the issue. Is there some way around this or am I doing something wrong?

Some more info following @mgilson's answer:
My system is 64-bit, and python can handle some very large integers:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.maxint
9223372036854775807
>>> tau = int(40000*365.25*24*3600)
>>> print tau
1262304000000
```

While gnuplot cannot:

```
gnuplot> tau = int(40000*365.25*24*3600)
gnuplot> print tau
-2147483648
```

Here's the plot file if you want to try it:

```
tau   = int(40000*365.25*24*3600)
delta = 10
kappa = 1e-6
omega = 2*pi/tau  # angular frequency
alpha = sqrt(omega/(2*kappa))  # a simplifying factor

# set the range of x and time, t
set xrange[0:3000]
step = int(10000*365.25*24*3600)

f(x,t) = alpha*delta*exp(-alpha*x)*(sin(omega*t-alpha*x)-cos(omega*t-alpha*x))
plot for [t=0:tau:step] f(x,t)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quickly putting some of this into the python interpreter:

```
>>> tau = int(40000*365.25*24*3600)
>>> tau
1262304000000L
>>> step = int(10000*365.25*24*3600)
>>> step
315576000000L
```

Notice the `L` at the end of the integers?  That means that these numbers overflowed the system's maximum integer size which is:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.maxint   #2**31 - 1
2147483647
```

for my system.  Python handles this gracefully by using a custom type (`long`) which allows the integer to occupy an unlimited number of bytes.  The way gnuplot handles this is that the overflow wraps around ...

```
gnuplot> tau = int(40000*365.25*24*3600)
gnuplot> print tau
-2147483648
```

Now you have negative numbers where you expected positive ones.

**EDIT**

It appears that gnuplot uses 4-byte integers no matter what python's `sys.maxint` is.  On my ubuntu x86_64 machine, python's `sys.maxint` is much larger than gnuplot's integer can handle (which is still capped at `2**31-1`).

Comment: Is there a different maxint for gnuplot cf python's sys.maxint? For me, `>>> sys.maxint` produces
9223372036854775807
(64-bit machine), while gnuplot repeats your numbers exactly.

Comment: My gnuplot build is 64-bit: `ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, stripped`, does this mean it should be able to handle 64-bit integers?

Comment: @adifferentben -- I don't know.  Just give it a try and see.  `print int(2**31)` -- on my ubuntu machine `python`'s maxint gives a much larger value than I can use in `gnuplot` (Build System: Linux x86_64), so it looks like gnuplot uses 4-byte integers no matter what.  Bringing python into it was merely because it was easy to demonstrate that your number overflows a 4-byte integer.